# Text centered on a background image [CSS]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to have a background image (in a div) which is always fully displayed on the screen (100 % for the width and height) with a text located on the middle of the div whatever the resolution. (see below) The div in green (#section_header) is the container of the background image.

http://uprapide.com/image/1023303-stack

I'm using JQuery to do this, using the ratio (width/height) of the image I want to display :

```
var resizeTimer; 

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(resizeFunction, 250);
});

function resizeFunction()
{
// TO set the image background dimensions
var number = (jQuery(window).width()) ;
   jQuery('#section_header').height(number/2.88);

// TO put the text on the middle
   var element_w = parseInt(jQuery('#section_header').css('width'),10); 
   var element_w2 = element_w/2;
   var space_border = number - number/2 - element_w2;
   jQuery('.column.two-third.column_column.bg_section_header').css('border-spacing',space_border/2+'px 0px');

 }
```

and the css

```
   #section_header {

    min-height: 255px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.column.two-third.column_column.bg_section_header {
display: table;
width: 100%;
 }
```

This solution works, but I would like to optimize the solution, because it is pretty slow to load. Any advice?

Thank you

Comment: Optimisation questions are, I would imagine, better suited to [**CodeReviewExchange**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done much simpler using purely CSS :

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="middle-div">
        <p>TEXT</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container { 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: red
}

.middle-div {
   color: white; 
}
```

See working example here : - [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvmynx8r/)

**EDIT**

To have the background image stretch and adjust to the screen width, add the following to your main container class :

```
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

*Obviously you would need to replace `url(images/bg.jpg)` with your own image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is it possible to manage the background-image size to stretch the screen (width) and also to have the prefect height?

Comment: Wow that works almost perfect, but with this "height: 100vh;" the image is set fullscreen , and not with the dimension of the image, because my container up to .container is the wrapper of the page. Any idea why it doesn't have the good height with this information ?

Comment: @Jibeee - Are you saying the image doesn't have the right aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this? If so you don't need jquery for that.

```
<div class="mrBigAssWithCenter"> Center Text </div>

.mrBigAssWithCenter{
     width: 80%; 
     height:80%;
    min-height:100px;
    background:url('http://s3.wallippo.com/thumbs/300x250/black-background-metal-hole-small-0973bb47dba91f8d8959dd9e308cd3ae.jpeg') no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #a1a1a1;
    color:#fff;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ThetHlaing10/8xncqbc2/)